# I want to redirect to another url if query string match

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

```
http://www.abcd.com/studio/index.php?mod=search&do=confirm_offer&offer_id=119
```

if match "`/studio/index.php?mod=search&do=confirm_offer&offer_id=119`" i want to redirect to "`http://abcd.com/checkout`"

i have already try both

```
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^http://www.fitfox.de/studio/index.php?mod=$1&do=confirm_offer&offer_id=$2 [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.fitfox.de/checkout/index.php [L,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mod=search&do=confirm_offer&offer_id=119$ [L]
#RewriteRule ^studio/index.php$ http://www.fitfox.de/checkout/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Nop, its not directory.

Comment: Test without the first `[L]` after `119$`

Comment: Please report the error (if any) you are getting. An `L` flag on the `RewriteCond` directive (as Croises has pointed out) would result in a 500 Internal Server error!